# Why source by seq as last parameter

Tags: f#

When I am looking on seq type in f#, the last parameter is always source like

```
Seq.pick chooser source
Seq.concat sources
```

why? Is that because of currying?

Comment: Yes it is common for function parameters to be ordered so as to make partial application more useful.

Answer (score 6):

Making the source the last parameter allows for partial application and the use of pipping like this:

```
let source = seq { 1..2 }
let chooser x = Some x
let result = source |> Seq.pick chooser
```

This is especially beneficial if you intend to pipe the sequence through a series of operations like this:

```
let source = seq { 1..2 }
let chooser x = Some x
let result = source 
             |> Seq.map (fun x -> x*x )
             |> Seq.pick chooser
```